# Unique Id for each element in a foreach loop in an asp.net mvc 3 view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a collection of ViewModels that I send back to from controller to the view

```
   public class CourseTableViewModel
    {
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public bool OwnerPremission { get; set; }
        public bool AddPermission { get; set; }
        public bool EditPermission { get; set; }
        public bool DeletePermission { get; set; }
        public bool ViewPermission { get; set; }
    }
```

So I have a list of these

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {     
            <tr>
               <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.OwnerPermission) </td>
               //.... rest here //
            </tr>

        }
```

This will loop around X amount of times depending on how VM's is being sent back but they all with have the same id and I want them different.

So I did this

```
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.OwnerPremission,new {@disabled = "disabled", @id = PermissionTypes.Owner.ToString() + counter})</td>
```

I am wondering if there is a better way.

**Edit**

So I did the template way(display not edit though) and have in it this

```
  <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OwnerPremission, new { @disabled = "disabled"})</td>
```

It renders this for the first one.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="[0].OwnerPremission" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="[0].OwnerPremission"></td>
```

There is no id just name. Why does it not show up?

Comment: Only better way would be to write your own HTML helper.

Comment: Maybe you should use a for(int i ... loop instead, to be able to give them different ids based on the i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an editor template for this view model which will ensure correct `id` and `name` attributes. So assuming your main view model is a collection of CourseTableViewModel or has a property that is a collection of CourseTableViewModel you could do the following in your main view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.CourseTableViewModel>
<table>
    <tr>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </tr>
</table>
```

and in the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CourseTableViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.CourseTableViewModel
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OwnerPremission, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
</td>
...
```

The editor template will be executed for each item in the view model collection and avoids you the need of writing any loops in your views. You just need to follow the naming conventions of those templates (it must be `called CourseTableViewModel.cshtml` because that's the type name used in the main view model collection).

---

UPDATE:

In the example I provided no id is being generated at all for the checkboxes. You could do the following to generate an unique id for each checkbox:

```
@model AppName.Models.CourseTableViewModel
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(
        x => x.OwnerPremission, 
        new { 
            @disabled = "disabled",
            id = HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName("OwnerPremission." + ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
        }
    )
</td>
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - first time I actually found a use for a template but I noticed it only makes a "name" tag for each one not a "id" for each one. Is that what it should be doing?

Comment: @chobo2, indeed, no id is generated in this case. Do you need the id name to be deterministic or you just need some id that should be unique?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Should the strongly typed html helper be generating the id? or is that only with like strongly typed textboxes?

Comment: @chobo2, no, even with textboxes it doesn't generate ids. I think that's because the editor template represents a collection. It's weird indeed. I thought it always generated unique ids but I am proven to be wrong.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov - Ya it is weird. I was not planning to use the Id's anyways for this part but I did not want them to break valid html(as the textboxes where generating the same id). So I have to check if I "id" is optional if it is then I will leave it as I don't need it at this time.